# Creating multivariable functions

Tags: calculus

Getting ready to go into multivariable calculus and I have a problem given to me by one of the teachers that will be teaching it next year. So here it is!

Write a multivariable function (i.e $z=f(x,y)$) for a linear function that contains the points $(-1,0), (0,2), (1,-1)$. I've calculated the lines that intersect each other and they are as follows $y=2x+2$ , $y=-3x+2$ , $y=-0.5x-0.5$. But now I need to create a multivariable function with domain $[-1,1]$ and range $[-1,2]$.

The 2nd part is creating a hypocycloid with points at $(1,0) , (0,1) , (-1,0) , (0,-1)$.

Comment: Please consider using a more descriptive title.

Comment: I don't know what this means. If you want $z=f(x,y)$, shouldn't we have ordered triples $(x,y,z)$ rather than ordered pairs? The hypocycloid is a nice question (if you know what that is). Related to it is the classic question: If you roll a coin of radius $1$ (without slipping) around a coin of radius $3$, how many complete turns does its head make?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin I know what a hypocycloid is but I'm wondering if I need to find an equation starting in polar and convert that into cartesian.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

The general form of a linear function of two variables is given by

$$
f(x,y) = Ax + By +C
$$

Plugging in the points you were given should give you three equations in the three unknowns $(A,B,C)$, which you can then solve.